# Syntax error at or near "$1" jdbc postgres -> SET var=?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

Trying to execute the following code :

```java
this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
        .createNativeQuery("SET app.variable = :variable")
        .setParameter("variable","variableValue")
        .executeUpdate();
```

It is giving me the following error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 26
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in JDBC or PostgreSQL.

It seems not a PostgreSQL issue as when I use the DBeaver using bind variables the query works fine.

Tried the same query by creating a prepared statement as well and the Result was same.

Comment: Given DBeaver also uses the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, it is likely that you either did something else in DBeaver, or DBeaver has special handling to give this the appearance of supporting parameters (e.g. by rewriting the query to use a literal on execute).

Comment: Got from DBeaver that it takes the parameter substitutes it in query itself and executes the final query on DB. Hence it is working on DBeaver. Finally SET statement cannot be used as parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL statement `SET` accepts no parameters. Only `SELECT`, `VALUES`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing, here is my solution. Instead of SET I use [set_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET), which is equivalent according to the [Postgres-Docs, Section "Notes"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html).

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select set_config('app.variable', :var, false);")
    .setParameter("var", variableValue)
    .getSingleResult();
```